# Android: RadioButton with two lines does not keep padding/margin

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-radiobutton

I have an XML with a `RadioGroup` and I'm programmatically adding `RadioButton` to the `RadioGroup`.
Nevertheless, in my `RadioButtons` I want to have items with two lines text, such as `Category name\nand parent category`.
Unfortunately, for some reason, the margin/padding isn't kept for the second line.

This is the way I add my button:

`RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) item.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
radioButton.setText(categoryName + "\n" + parentCategoryText);`

This is my button in the XML:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/categoryName"
    style="@style/mpRefineNormalText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/paddingCategoryListItemTextSize"
    tools:text="Category name\nand parent category"/>
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please show us how you added the radiobutton

Comment: use android:drawablePadding

Comment: @amy I tried it, but not working

Comment: @manulorenzo please in the question. not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, since when setting the name of the category programmatically, it had some blank spaces before the name, hence the "aggregated" padding to the left of the `RadioButton` in the first line.
Thanks everybody for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Its working for me

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/categoryName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="Category name\nand parent category"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>
```

Comment: what you have changed ? please describe.